# Get 3rd Saturday of the month between startdate and enddate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I want to get date which is the 3rd Saturday of the month between two dates. I have done but it's not what i want.

```
NSInteger count = 0;
NSInteger saturday = 7;

// Set the incremental interval for each interaction.
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[oneDay setDay:1];

// Using a Gregorian calendar.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *currentDate = [[UtilityClass sharedObject] stringToDate:@"2016-06-17" withFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *toDate = [[UtilityClass sharedObject] stringToDate:@"2016-08-17" withFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];


// Iterate from fromDate until toDate
while ([currentDate compare:toDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
[dateComponents setWeekdayOrdinal:3];

if (dateComponents.weekday == saturday) {
    count++;
    NSLog(@"Date = %@",currentDate);
}

// "Increment" currentDate by one day.
currentDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay
                                                    toDate:currentDate
                                                   options:0];
}
```

In my code i have successfully get Saturday but it's all Saturdays get which is in between `startdate` & `enddate`.
I have also try this :

> [dateComponents setWeekdayOrdinal:3];
>   but not working.

This is my log

```
2016-06-17 11:29:18.319 Floacstation[1715:84848] Current Date :2016-06-16 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.319 Floacstation[1715:84848] To Date : 2016-08-16 18:30:00 +0000

2016-06-17 11:29:18.320 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-06-19 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.320 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-06-26 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.320 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-07-03 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.320 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-07-10 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.320 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-07-17 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.320 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-07-24 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.320 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-07-31 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.321 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-08-07 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:29:18.321 Floacstation[1715:84848] Saturday Date = 2016-08-14 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: @Sneha i edited my post with logs

Comment: print currentDate & toDate into NSLog & show it too..

Comment: Done now i log current date and to date

Comment: check my answer....

Comment: Thanks but not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114907/discussion-between-sneha-and-kamlesh-shingarakhiya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason:**

Notice that you have entered date `17th` but its returning you `16th`.. As it is considering `UTC` format whenever you are `printing NSDate in NSLog` or `converting it explicitly to NSString`.

> Whenever You want the date in string Then Use `NSDateFormatter` as i have used in this Code..

The problem you are facing is just because of that.
so, Wherever you have used Date, just `replace the method of converting date` into String & check again for Output..

Try this one... It must give you proper answer...

```
NSInteger count = 0;
NSInteger saturday = 7;

// Set the incremental interval for each interaction.
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[oneDay setDay:1];

// Using a Gregorian calendar.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *currentDate = [[UtilityClass sharedObject] stringToDate:@"2016-06-17" withFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *toDate = [[UtilityClass sharedObject] stringToDate:@"2016-08-17" withFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];


// Iterate from fromDate until toDate
while ([currentDate compare:toDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
[dateComponents setWeekdayOrdinal:3];

if (dateComponents.weekday == saturday) {
    count++;

    if (count==3) {
            NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            formatter.dateFormat=@"dd MM YYYY";

            NSLog(@"Date = %@",[formatter stringFromDate:currentDate]);
        }
  }

}
```

> // There's no need to Increment this Date..

```
// "Increment" currentDate by one day.
// currentDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay
//                                                    toDate:currentDate
//                                                   options:0];
```

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Log value 
Current Date :2016-06-16 18:30:00 +0000
To Date : 2016-08-16 18:30:00 +0000
Date = 04 07 2016
And in my calendar show it is monday

Answer (score 1):

`NSCalendar` has powerful skills to do that without repeat loops

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *currentDate = [[UtilityClass sharedObject] stringToDate:@"2016-06-17" withFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *toDate = [[UtilityClass sharedObject] stringToDate:@"2016-08-17" withFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.weekday = 7;
components.weekdayOrdinal = 3;
components.month = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:currentDate];

NSDate *nextThirdSaturday = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:currentDate matchingComponents: components options: NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
if (nextThirdSaturday && [nextThirdSaturday compare:toDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
   NSLog(@"%@", nextThirdSaturday);
} else {
   NSLog(@"Not Found");
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want the 3rd saturday calculated from the start date and within the range of start and end date use this

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.weekday = 7;

__block NSInteger count = 1;
__block NSDate *found;
[calendar enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate:currentDate matchingComponents:components options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime usingBlock:^(NSDate *date, BOOL exactMatch, BOOL *stop) {
   if (count == 3) { found = date; }
   if  (found || [date compare:toDate] == NSOrderedDescending) *stop = YES;
   count++;
}];
NSLog(@"%@", found);
```

Comment: i getting only startdate .

Comment: I tested it in a Swift playground and it's working fine

Comment: For the given start date: One, which is tomorrow (2016-06-18).

Comment: you getting 3rd sat. of this month. But i want to 3rd sat. which is in between startdate & enddate

Comment: Unfortunately your question is a bit ambiguous (*3rd saturday of the month* is tomorrow). OK, what result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger count = 0;
NSInteger saturday = 7;

// Set the incremental interval for each interaction.
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[oneDay setDay:1];

// Using a Gregorian calendar.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *currentDate = [[UtilityClass sharedObject] stringToDate:@"2016-06-17" withFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *toDate = [[UtilityClass sharedObject] stringToDate:@"2016-08-17" withFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];


// Iterate from fromDate until toDate
while ([currentDate compare:toDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
[dateComponents setWeekdayOrdinal:3];

if (dateComponents.weekday == saturday) {
    count++;
    NSLog(@"3rd Satureday Date = %@",currentDate);
    if(count == 3)
        break;
}

// "Increment" currentDate by one day.
currentDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay
                                                    toDate:currentDate
                                                   options:0];
}
```

This is my log

```
2016-06-17 11:07:53.335 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-06-17 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:07:53.335 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-06-24 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:07:53.335 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-07-01 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:07:53.335 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-07-08 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:07:53.335 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-07-15 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:07:53.336 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-07-22 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:07:53.336 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-07-29 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:07:53.336 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-08-05 18:30:00 +0000
2016-06-17 11:07:53.336 Floacstation[1568:75953] Date = 2016-08-12 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: what is the value of nslog?

Comment: getting only one date of saturday and aslo that value i get it wrong it was not saturday date

Comment: thats the 3rd satureday date :)

Comment: but i getting only one date but when i check calendar it showing two dates which is also saturday

Comment: its only getting first 3 dates of sat.
log value : - 2016-06-17
2016-06-24
2016-07-01

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, the date you want is `2016-07-02`?
Try this:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2016-06-16" formatString:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *toDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2016-08-17" formatString:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSLog(@"Oh, %@ is the 3rd Saturday", [[currentDate dateByAddingWeeks:2] dateByAddingDays:(saturday - currentDate.weekday + 1)]);
```

I use a 3rd library called [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools).